# Swagger API Docs XOR

Tags: api, yaml, xor, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm wondering if it's possible, to use an XOR in a swagger.yaml/json
If I have something like this for example:

```
PostableEntity:
  properties:
    first_property:
      type: string
    second_property:
      type: string
      minLength: 1
      description: foo
    third_property:
      type: number
  required:
    - third_property
```

Now how can I make first_property required if second_property is not set and the other way around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conditional properties cannot be modeled, but you might go for a workaround using polymorphism. You could create a parent model `P` with `third_property` and two child models (`C1` and `C2`), one (`C1`) with `first_property` the other one (`C2`) with `second_property`. Using the `allOf` keyword and a `discriminator` field, you'll get either a model with properties form `P+C1` or `P+C2`.

See chapter **Composition and Inheritance (Polymorphism)** in the [documentation](http://swagger.io/specification/).

> Swagger allows combining and extending model definitions using the
>   allOf property of JSON Schema, in effect offering model composition.
>   allOf takes in an array of object definitions that are validated
>   independently but together compose a single object.

**HINT:**

Don't get confused when your swagger editor reports you the following error using the `allOf` keyword: **No additional properties allowed, but property <foo> is set**

There is currently a bug that is already reported on github, see [this link](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/760).

Comment: That helped me. Thank you very much. (:

Answer (score 0):

In OpenAPI 3.1 this seems to work better now: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Swagger-Open-Source-Tools/Defining-conditional-attributes-in-OpenAPI/m-p/222693#M2058